# Google Chart - DataTable inside a form

Tags: forms, datatable, google-visualization

I have a table created with DataTable of Google Chart, which has a column with a drop-down list. In this way the user can set the proper value of a row.
I am working in Python and Flask and I can retrieve the request data correctly. The problem is that the table, given the amount of data, is showed in pages, each one with 20 rows. When I retrieve the request I get only those 20 rows, so I have no way to know what the user set in the other pages.
How can I get the values of all pages?

Moreover, I noticed that when I change page and then I go back, the table forgets the user changes, so I think I should be careful also to this fact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved the problem by using a dictionary containing all the changes made to the table and updating the html string inside the table to keep the content updated.